# php gettimestamp stopping execution

Tags: php, codeigniter, timestamp

hey guys was hoping you could help me out.

I am working on a project and was having a weird problem,

I initially had this code

```
   public function create_visit($host_id,$type){
    $ip=$this->ci->input->ip_address();


    $visit=$this->ci->host_model->get_visit($host_id,$this->ci->input->ip_address());

    if($visit->num_rows()>0){//already created
        $date_week=new DateTime();
        $date_week->modify('-1 weeks');


        $visit_time=strtotime($visit->row()->create_date);
        if($date_week->getTimestamp()<$visit_time){
        $this->ci->input->set_cookie(COOKIE_PREFIX.'visit_id', $visit->row()->id, COOKIE_TIMEOUT);
        return;
        }


    }
```

problem was right after this line `if($date_week->getTimestamp()<$visit_time){` there was no execution. It worked fine on xamp , but not on my clients server.
 I did a bunch of echos and eventually found out the culprit so instead I changed the code to this

```
public function create_visit($host_id,$type){
$ip=$this->ci->input->ip_address();


$visit=$this->ci->host_model->get_visit($host_id,$this->ci->input->ip_address());

if($visit->num_rows()>0){//already created
$date_week=time()-604800;


$visit_time=strtotime($visit->row()->create_date);
if($date_week<$visit_time){
$this->ci->input->set_cookie(COOKIE_PREFIX.'visit_id', $visit->row()->id, COOKIE_TIMEOUT);
return;
}
```

}

its working now (with only the mentioned changed) but i really want to figure out what the problem was.. Am using codeigniter with hmvc plugin if that helps...

Comment: What does `phpinfo` tell you about the version used on the remote host vs the version used locally (xampp)? Also: check the php.ini files, compare the differences between both environments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely problem is the version of php on the server. `getTimestamp` is available from php 5.3 on.